# Why is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k}{(1+r)^k} > 1/r$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Why is $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k}{(1+r)^k} > 1/r$$ where $r$ is interest rate (small number)

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Geometric series formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula), for $-1<q<1$:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}q^k=\frac{1}{1-q} $$
Derive by q
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kq^{k-1}=\frac{1}{(1-q)^2} $$
Multiply by q
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kq^{k}=\frac{q}{(1-q)^2} $$
Substitute $q=\frac{1}{1+r}$
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k}{(1+r)^{k}}=\frac{1+r}{r^2}=\frac{1}{r^2}+\frac{1}{r} >\frac{1}{r}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $|x|<1$, then
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kx^k=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} $$